# Express + Consolidate + Hogan: ` Error: cannot find module 'hogan' ` with code straight from consolidate docs

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, hogan.js

I'm getting an `Error: cannot find module 'hogan'` when I send a request to the node.js server implemented in Coffeescript here:

https://gist.github.com/wmayner/306c89d7f8fbeed3f098

I've installed the dependencies `hogan.js`, [`consolidate`](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js), and `express`.

I've reproduced the example code from [`consolidate`](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js)'s documentation (reproduced below) almost exactly, so I'm having trouble seeing where this error is coming from. It looks like it should work.

From the [`consolidate` docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js):

```
var express = require('express')
  , cons = require('consolidate')
  , app = express();

// assign the swig engine to .html files
app.engine('html', cons.swig);

// set .html as the default extension 
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

I've also tried declaring `hogan = require('hogan.js')' as a dependency.

Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

---

**Note:** The gist above differs from the `consolidate` docs in that I'm setting the `view engine` to `hogan` rather than `html`. This is because I'd rather use `.hogan` than `.html` for my template file extensions (I've tried `.html` and I get the same error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gist sets `hogan` as `view engine`, but that should be `html` like in the Consolidate docs:

```
// tell Express to use Consolidates 'hogan' renderer for .html templates
engines = require 'consolidate'
engine = 'hogan'
app.engine 'html', engines[engine]

// tell Express to use '.html' as extension to find views with .render()
app.set 'view engine', 'html'
```

**EDIT:** realizing that perhaps you want to use `.hogan` as extension for your template files, you could use this instead:

```
app.engine 'hogan', engines[engine]
app.set 'view engine', 'hogan'
```

Comment: But `engine is 'hogan'`, so that's in fact what I've already tried in the gist with `app.engine 'html', engines[engine] \
  app.set 'view engine', engine` (I do in fact want to use `.hogan` rather than `.html`).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I didn't realize that the first argument to `app.engine` is also the file extension of the templates, and I didn't notice that you'd changed it to 'hogan' in your edit - only saw the change in the second line. My bad!